# Dynamically invoking a method on the list

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, reflection

I need to find max or min in the list of elements {2,3,4}

```
 double[] doubleList = { 2, 3, 4 };
 doubleList.Max(); // return 4
```

How can I dynamically invoke a correct method?

I can implement this for two elements as described in the link
   http://tutorials.csharp-online.net/Attributes_and_Reflection%E2%80%94Late_Binding

EDIT:
Something like this:

```
 string methodName = "Min";
  var t = Type.GetType("System.Math");
  MethodInfo genericFunction = t.GetMethod(methodName, types);
  object val = genericFunction.Invoke(t, params);
```

Comment: How do you determine which is the correct method?

Comment: You're showing code that will compile and do at runtime do what you want it to do. Show the code using reflection you currently have. If nothing, try a web search and show some effort. You do know `Max()` is an extension method that isn't defined on `List<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for `Enumerable`'s Min function instead of `Math`'s.

```
double[] doubleList = { 2, 3, 4 };

string methodName = "Min";

var t = typeof(Enumerable);
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                 .Where(m => m.Name == methodName && m.ReturnType == typeof(double))
                 .FirstOrDefault();

object val = method.Invoke(t, new object[]{ doubleList });
```